# UIButton Subclass Title Changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, subclass

I am using a subclass of UIButton and want to be able to do some stuff whenever the title is changed. Rather than adding my own method, is it possible to subclass the method:

```
-(void)setTitle:(NSString *)title forState:(UIControlState)state
```

And then make my changes here? I have included the method in my subclass, but it causes the title not to be set, kind of expected. But I can't set the title myself in that method as the UILabel is read-only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that you never called the super implementation of the function. Try it like this:

```
-(void)setTitle:(NSString *)title forState:(UIControlState)state {
    [super setTitle:title forState:state];
    // some other code
}
```